# how do I avoid html_safe when using gsub to insert links?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xss

a simplified example would be this:

```rb
def expand_links(message)
  message = strip_tags(message)
  message = message.gsub('[register]') { link_to('register', new_user_path) }
  message = message.gsub('[login]') { link_to('login', new_sessions_path) }
  message.html_safe
end
```

I'm using `strip_tags` but to be sure there isn't a chance of XSS.

so what would be the proper way to do this without `strip_tags` and `html_safe`?

Comment: You don't really need to check for xss if you're inserting your own links, just if you're dealing with user submitted links/content

Comment: @Iceman `message` could potentially be tainted with user input (even if I'm avoiding it for now but having proper XSS prevention could allow me to have better error messages)

Comment: Would the `sanitize` method serve you better? https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html

Comment: @Iceman oh thanks a lot! I kept the initial `strip_tags` (to prevent random links), then `gsub`s then `sanitize(message, tags: ['a'], attributes: ['href'])`, works very well in my limited testing

Answer (score 3):

here is what I did from @iceman's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55794182/how-do-i-avoid-html-safe-when-using-gsub-to-insert-links#comment98257435_55794182):

```rb
  def expand_links(message)
    message = strip_tags(message)
    message = message.gsub('[register]') { link_to('register', new_user_path) }
    message = message.gsub('[login]') { link_to('login', new_sessions_path) }
    sanitize(message, tags: ['a'], attributes: ['href'])
  end
```

(BTW sanitize doesn't work with symbols)

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html

Comment: Great, you can accept your own answer, that's perfectly valid practice!